# Translation Manager - sending job to TMS returns "The client is inactive"

Tags: content-manager, translation-manager

After setting up source and target publications for integration with TMS, I sent a test job and got the following "The client is inactive" error:

[image]

The stack trace suggests I got response back from TMS (it takes a response as a parameter) but I've no idea what this error means.

Enabling verbose logging generated a SDLJobRequest.xml file but no more detail.

Is this an issue on the TMS side - is TMS the "client" in this error message or is that TM?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that TMS configuration that you use to configure TM is not active.

GUID that you Enter in "Configuration ID" field in TM source configuration corresponds to particular configuration in TMS. And that configuration is not active.

Got to TSM -> Setup -> Organisations -> [Your organisation] -> Configurations

Open configuration that you use in TM

And set "Active" checkbox